# Create word with initial name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a Word document from Excel with an initial filename, to be faster during the saving process. It is not possible for the Word doc to be a macro-file, because I can not save them in our SharePoint.

I do the following before opening the Word doc:

- Select specific text passages from a log file (txt) and lay them in the Excel doc.
- In the Excel doc, they are stored for Controlling works.
- From there, some of the Information is going to be transferred to the Word document and then saved for logging cases.

I found some ways to change the name in the active.document, but the Word document should not be the active.document.

I want to initialize the desired name before the Word doc is created: I want to show this name in the document window's caption and also have it suggested when the user first tries to save.

I tried the following, but it says it is not possible because it is a read-only property:

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()

    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    With wrdApp
        .Name = "desiredFileName"
    End With

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

End Sub
```

Is it somehow possible to give the desired file Name, without actually saving the file?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to give a document a name without saving it - that's how Word is designed. What is possible:

Change the caption of the document window:

```
wrdDoc.ActiveWindow.Caption = "desired file name"
```

Note that, should the user for some reason create additional windows for the same document this caption will *not* carry over to them.

Pre-set the suggested file name when the Save As dialog box is displayed:

```
 With wrdApp.Dialogs(Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFileSummaryInfo) 'enum value 86
   .Title = "desired file name"
   .Execute
 End With
```

This will write the string to the built-in document property `Title`, which Word references when displaying Save As for an unsaved document. For some reason, using `Document.BuiltinDocumentProperties(wdPropertyTitle)` does not work, so one has to go over the built-in dialog box route. For more information see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/SetDefFilename.htm.

Comment: Both of your codes are not working, it says always that the field is read-only. The "built-in dialog box route" is somehow to advanced for me. I am not able to get this working.

Comment: ActiveWindow.Caption works fine for me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign `Name` to `Application` object which is not correct.

See if following code helps you:

```
Sub CreateNewWordDoc()

    Dim wrdApp As Object 'Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Object 'Word.Document

    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wrdApp.Visible = True

    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add
    With wrdDoc
        .SaveAs "desiredFileName"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thats a solution, but not to my problem ;-) I dont want to save it immediately, i want to give a suggestet name of the file. I want to create everyday this word document, but i have to modify the filename a bit. Thank you.